# Program crashing because of these pointers and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My code is crashing because of these pointer variables. what is wrong with them?

variable declarations in main

```
char* fname = (first_name_length*sizeof(char));

char* lname = (last_name_length*sizeof(char));

char* pfname = &fname[0];

char* plname = &lname[0];
```

function

```
void get_first_name(FILE* fp, int length, char* pfname){

char c;
int i = 0;
int number_of_conversions;

//char* first_name = malloc(length*sizeof(char));

number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

while (!isspace(c)){

    pfname[i] = c;

    number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

}

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the declarations of `fname` and `lname`?

Comment: store names in them? why does that matter in this context?

Comment: The assignment makes no sense. Are you trying to allocate memory for them?

Comment: yes. allocate enough memory for the list of character i have. am trying to transfer an array from a void function to main.

Comment: On which line does the code crash?

Comment: In your `get_first_name` function, you never advance `i` in the `while` loop; you wind up writing to `pfname[0]` repeatedly.

Comment: Additionally, you do not end your array with a `'\0'` in this code, which would cause you problems if you are treating the resulting array as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In the first 2 lines you are assigning the result of math to a character arrayTry
    char first[50],last[50];    char tmp[]="john Smith";

```
strncpy(first,tmp,4);

// new line as per comments below 

first[4]='\0';

// typo fixed below ( removed n) 

strcpy (last,tmp+5);

char *pfirst =&first[0];

// or more correctly 
char *plast =last
```

Comment: This use of `strncpy()` will not `0`-terminate the destination `char`-arrays, thus they are no valid C-"strings". Also for the 2nd call to `strncpy()` the 3rd parameter is missing.

Comment: Yeah you right i'll edit my answer. Problem is I just use my phone for this, no gcc so I can't verify my code. Did you down vote?

Answer (score 0):

```
char* fname = (first_name_length*sizeof(char));
char* lname = (last_name_length*sizeof(char));
```

This is not how you allocate memory in C. You can either allocate memory statically:

```
char fname[first_name_length]; //This assumes that first_ and last_name_length are
char lname[last_name_length];  //constants
```

Or dynamically like so:

```
char* fname = malloc(first_name_length*sizeof(char)); //first_ and last_name_length can
char* lname = malloc(last_name_length*sizeof(char));  //be constants or variables
```

Comment: i know i forgot malloc. but it still crashes.

Comment: It crashes in the same place as determined by a debugger?

Comment: it says program has stopped working. doesnt tell anything about the issue but when i remove these variables the program works fine so.

Comment: For us to help you further, we would need to know more. Deal with the issues which John Bode and I mention in the question comments. If that doesn't fix your problem, you will need to determine exactly where your code is failing. This can be done through a debugger, or if that isn't an option, by throwing a bunch of `printf` statements into your code to narrow down what is going on when the program fails.

Comment: i can tell you that the program fails at pfname[i] = c;

Comment: That would indicate a problem with the value you are passing to `pfname`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: @alk Indeed, but it does no harm to be specific.

Comment: A specific and  less error prone approach would be: `char* fname = malloc(first_name_length * sizeof *fname);` It for example would survive a `#define char wchar_t`.

Comment: doesn't make any sense since it works fine when i store c in a function local variable. its just a character being passed to a character array through a pointer. how can that crash a program?

Comment: If `pfname` is `NULL` or a completely invalid address, attempting to write to it could absolutely crash a program.

Comment: You also need to add 1 when allocating memory for the terminating null byte, i.e. `malloc( (first_name_length+1)*sizeof(char) )`

Comment: do i really need a null terminator for a char array? its not like i dont know the size. null is pointless at this point

Comment: If you are going to run it through any string functions, absolutely.

Comment: You don't need the null terminator while you are building the string, but you aren't adding one when you are done building, either.

Comment: all i need to do is output the characters so i don't think i need one as long as i know how long it is.

Comment: And how will you know how long it is? You aren't passing the length back in your function. `strlen` will not work properly without a null terminator.